# Array to Binary Expression

Tags: c#, linq

Given `x => x.LastName`,

How do I convert something like `.Where({"Doe", "Don", "Donna"}.Contains(x.LastName))`?

I need to convert this `.Contains` Expression into

```
.Where(x => x.LastName == "Doe" || x.LastName == "Don" || x.LastName == "Donna")
```

So basically given an array `{"Doe", "Don", "Donna"}` and a Member Expression `x.LastName`, how do I dynamically build a valid `BinaryExpression` as above?

Okay so a little background, I am trying to build a LINQ interface to a NoSQL database that has no idea how to handle an `Enumerable.Contains` `MemberCallExpression`. So I am trying to translate that `Enumerable.Contains` into a simple `OrElse` Expression that the Database can handle.

I can get `x.LastName` from the `MemberCallExpression`'s `Arguments[0]`, and I have figured out how to get an Enumerable of Constants from the Expression, that I have been able to build a `List<BinaryExpression>` out of, by enumerating the Constants and saying

```
Expressions.Add(Expression.Equal(node.Arguements[0], Expression.Constant(item)));
```

How do I take that list of `BinaryExpression`s and build a valid `BinaryExpression` of the form `Expressions[0] OrElse Expressions[1] OrElse Expressions[2]`.

I tried:

```
BinaryExpression expression = Expressions[0];
for (var idx = 1; idx < Expressions.Count - 1; idx++)
{
     expression += Expression.OrElse(Expressions[idx], Expressions[idx   +1]);
}
```

However `+=` is not valid on a `BinaryExpression`. And I am unsure how to actually append another Binary Expression onto an existing BinaryExpression...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave my previous answer for future reference, because I think Expression construction is not easy so that example may be useful for someone. As to the problem, chaining expressions is quite simple. you should use the `Expression.OrElse` method for that:

```
BinaryExpression expression = Expressions[0];
for (var idx = 1; idx < Expressions.Count - 1; idx++)
{
    expression = Expression.OrElse(expression, Expressions[idx]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is basically the right answer, my initial logic was flawed in that I ended the loop one iteration too soon, so it should be idx < Expressions.Count, not Expressions.Count - 1.  And really since Expressions is a local variable it should be expressions instead.  This solved my problem though.  And I also want to thank GSerg for reformatting my code into something understandable.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, @H.D.H. this bumps be over the 500 points reputation, which opens some more privileges :)

Comment: My pleasure, Tsahi Asher, you almost make Expressions seem easy.  I am a bit ashamed at how close I was and still had to ask for help.

Comment: I think it was RavenDb, one of the lead developers of that database made a comment that it took them longer to implement a LINQ interface to there database, than it took them to build the database engine itself.   Expressions are not simple, for most people anyway I would wager they are actually quite intimidating.  At least if your experience isn't compiler design.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arr = {"Doe", "Don", "Donna"};
BinaryExpression exp = null;
MemberExpression member = ... //get the "x.LastName" expression
foreach (String name in arr) {
    BinaryExpression eq = Expression.Equal(member, name);
    if (exp == null) {
        exp = eq;
    }
    else {
        exp = Expression.OrElse(exp, eq);
    }
}

Type delegateType = typeof(Func<T, bool>); //T is your entity type, e.g. Person
ParameterExpression arg = ... //the "x" in "x.LastName"

//construct the lambda expression x => [expr].
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, expr, arg);
```

then, you can feed that to `.Where()`:

```
.Where(lambda);
```